# OpenGL cannot Draw lines, but quad is working

Tags: java, opengl

I can't figure out why this:

```
glPushMatrix();
GL11.glBindTexture(this.target, this.textureID);
glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
glTranslated(posX, posY, 0);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    {
        glTexCoord2d(posXLeft, posYTop);
        glVertex2d(0, 0);
        glTexCoord2d(posXLeft, posYBottom);
        glVertex2d(0, verH);
        glTexCoord2d(posXRight, posYBottom);
        glVertex2d(verW, verH);
        glTexCoord2d(posXRight, posYTop);
        glVertex2d(verW, 0);
    }
    glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

is working perfectly, where posX and posY are obviously the position in pixels, posXLeft etc is the ratio of the texture to show.

But this:

```
glPushMatrix();
GL11.glBindTexture(this.target, this.textureID);
glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
glTranslated(posX, posY, 0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    {
    glVertex2d(10, 10);
    glVertex2d(800, 600);
}
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

isn't. And it should be even easier to draw lines instead of a piece of a texture.

What I want to reach is to add some zig-zag lines on a texture to simulate cracks as it is damaged or broken, but I can't even draw a single line, so I am stuck here.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

You still got texturing enabled in your line drawing code. But you don't specify texture coordinates, so you'll draw your line with a solid color as defined by texture at the currently set texture coordinate.

My suggestion: Disable texturing for drawing that line.

Answer (score 0):

As said by datenwolf you have to disable the texturing, thes thing is that than you have to re-enable it, although you will have problems the next cycle of drawing if that property is not set correctly.

the solution is:

```
glPushMatrix();
GL11.glBindTexture(this.target, this.textureID);
glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glTranslated(posX, posY, 0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    {
    glVertex2d(10, 10);
    glVertex2d(800, 600);
}
glEnd();
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glPopMatrix();
```

and that should solve your problem.